# Expanding a given Group into a larger group

Tags: group-theory

Id please like to know when and how can we 'expand' a Group into a larger Group. So what I mean by expend is replace each element with 2 or more elements such that the new Group has the old structure as a Quotient Group. 
Is this sometimes possible?

Comment: It seems taking the direct product with another group qualifies as "expanding" in your sense.

Comment: The term is actually "extension." See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_extension for details.

Comment: What about finding or creating a Group with a large and complex quotient diagram?

Comment: Instead of putting a followup question in comments, you should post a new question. However, your followup question is quite a bit vaguer than your original question. So before posting it as a new question, try to formulate it as a precise mathematical question.